# outliers in time series

Tags: python, time-series, anomaly-detection, jupyter

I have a data set like the following
[image]

where the rows are dates and the columns are values recorded by different sensors on those dates.

Before working with the data for the purpose of predicting it, I would like to remove the anomalies.

**Standard deviation**
The first thing I found on the internet was to get data out of the standard deviation
so working with this, I've come up with things like this.

[image]

I search a little more in interet I have read that it is not a good method when the data does not follow a normal distribution.
So I did a shapiro test for normality and the H0 hypothesis was rejected, my data doesn't look like a Guassian

But if I plot a histogram, the data looks like half a bell.

[image]

**IQR** in some sites I read about the IQR method which is based on ordering the data, so I went to test it too, and with a value of n of 1.5 it gave me results equal to the standard deviation

[image]

**tsmoothie** At this point I was quite confused and I found this library and this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-time-series-anomaly-detection-981cf1e1ca13)
I thought maybe it was a better way than the above and tried to test it too.
But I ran into the problem that it has many methods and I honestly don't know which one to use.

**PCA + IQR** I kept looking on the internet and I found this [link](http://ttps://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-time-series-anomaly-detection-981cf1e1ca13) that left me more confused, it is a case similar to mine where there are several time series of various sensors.
But after applying pca and iqr the following are anomalous points
[image]
For me, this sensor has a normal behavior, but it marks many anomalous points, and in sensors with points  with high values, it does not mark them as anomalous

**So in this context, what would be the best approach to detect the anomalous points before working with the data? What do you get used to doing?**

Comment: You tried different solutions before defining your problem. What is anomalous to you ? High value ? Unusual value ? An impossible one ? A sudden change ? A change in trend ? Differents techniques fit different definition. There is no one size fit all algo.

Comment: I do not know. I am working with traffic volume data. I wanted to eliminate anomalies before analyzing them, looking for patterns and predicting them. What is usually taken to be anomalous?

Comment: The definition of anomaly is task dependent, and must reflect what the model is to be used for.